# Usb Ethernet adapter stopped working on Dell xps 15 laptop ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, usb, dell, ethernet

The dell xps 15 is dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (desktop) and windows 10.  The usb-to-ethernet adapter was working fine yesterday.  But it stopped working today.  I tried windows 10 side and it's not working either.

The wired network icon is not even showing on the top right corner of desktop.

The adapter works on another laptop.  The usb port works with usb keyboard/mouse.

What can I do to diagnose it and fix it?

Thanks!

```
@xps15:~$ sudo ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1446  bytes 94704 (94.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1446  bytes 94704 (94.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp59s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::6b4:3ab1:13e6:13e6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9c:b6:d0:c2:04:4f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2143  bytes 1175486 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1688  bytes 248747 (248.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

@xps15:~$ sudo dmesg | grep usb
[    0.384063] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.384065] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.384091] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.206474] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.206476] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.206477] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.206479] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.206480] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.208684] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.208686] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.208687] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.208689] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.208690] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.209361] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.548083] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.698018] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=062a, idProduct=4101
[    1.698019] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.698020] usb 1-1: Product: 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
[    1.698020] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
[    1.824095] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.973507] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=e301
[    1.973508] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.100117] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.252020] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=27c6, idProduct=5395
[    2.252022] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.252023] usb 1-7: Product: Goodix Fingerprint Device 
[    2.252023] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: HTMicroelectronics
[    2.252024] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: HTK32
[    2.380359] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.546052] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=671d
[    2.546054] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.546055] usb 1-12: Product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
[    2.546055] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: CN0VGCNHLOG008A9ABN1A00
[    2.552447] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.552448] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.555450] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:062A:4101.0001/input/input7
[    2.612233] hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[    2.612367] input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0002/input/input8
[    2.672527] hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[    3.160855] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    3.181505] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/input/input11
[    3.181549] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.190521] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    3.691725] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 dell_laptop(+) dell_wmi dell_smbios intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof snd_hda_intel(+) snd_hda_codec intel_rapl snd_hda_core snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_pcm kvm_intel dell_wmi_descriptor snd_seq_midi dcdbas kvm snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul i915(+) ath10k_pci crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel nouveau(+) ath10k_core pcbc ath mac80211 snd_seq btusb aesni_intel mxm_wmi btrtl ttm btbcm btintel snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper aes_x86_64 uvcvideo snd_timer crypto_simd glue_helper videobuf2_vmalloc cryptd videobuf2_memops drm bluetooth videobuf2_v4l2 snd videobuf2_core rtsx_pci_ms i2c_algo_bit videodev mei_me fb_sys_fops intel_cstate processor_thermal_device(+) idma64 syscopyarea sysfillrect intel_rapl_perf
[    3.691759]  joydev input_leds cdc_acm media cfg80211 ecdh_generic serio_raw memstick soundcore virt_dma intel_soc_dts_iosf mei sysimgblt intel_lpss_pci(+) shpchp intel_lpss intel_pch_thermal int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone wmi dell_smo8800 intel_hid video int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid rtsx_pci_sdmmc psmouse nvme nvme_core rtsx_pci ahci libahci i2c_hid hid
[    3.704427] audit: type=1400 audit(1564454671.763:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=772 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.339862] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   12.339864] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   12.339865] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   12.339866] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic xhci-hcd
[   12.339867] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:3a:00.0
[   12.340174] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[   12.340175] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   12.340176] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   12.340177] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic xhci-hcd
[   12.340178] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:3a:00.0
[   33.246559] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[   33.246805] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[   88.295338] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   88.295340] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   88.295341] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   88.295342] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic xhci-hcd
[   88.295343] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:3a:00.0
[   88.295591] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[   88.295592] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   88.295593] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   88.295594] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic xhci-hcd
[   88.295595] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:3a:00.0
[  128.920592] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  128.920864] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `ifconfig -a`, `dmesg | grep usb`, and `lsusb -v` ?

Comment: Hm, based on the result, I don't see your usb ethernet on the list. Do you have another usb ethernet to check?

Comment: added output of ifconfig -a and dmesg.  lsusb -v is too long and I'm not able to add in the text.

Comment: Also, with usb ethernet plugged in, can you check it from the bios settings if it is detected? And make sure to enable external usb port under System Configuration > USB Configuration from your BIOS. Because generic mouse & keyboard will always work even without enabling external usb port, but it won't work for another type of usb.

Comment: The usb-to-ethernet works on a different laptop.  I just tried again right now.

Comment: Then please check your bios settings just to make sure.

Comment: Just checked, external usb support is enabled.

Comment: As I'm typing now, I saw a 'greyed out' wired icon on the top right corner of my display, then disappeared.

Comment: Because it doesn't work on Windows too, and nothing seems wrong in the bios settings, my best bet is either lack of power which is very very rare case especially for a notebook, or, there is conflict with another plugged in usb 3.0 device based on my past experience.

Comment: There isn't any other usb connected to the laptop, except the mouse/keyboard.  I disconnected it and it didn't show any difference.  The battery power is 85%.  Thank you very much for your effort helping.